# Filling a grid in Photoshop Elements

Tags: adobe-photoshop-elements

(I have created a grid of 357 squares in Photoshop Elements - 21 x 17.  I need to fill it with about 28 different patterns which I have in rectangular image files.  Each pattern will be repeated multiple times to create a patchwork carpet design. Is there a way I can do this quickly rather than filling the squares one by one?